# Prompt max length

Tags: javascript, html, specifications

Using prompt() I am generating some html to and need to know the maximum length that I can put in the popup.

I can't find anything in the spec about this, wondering if someone can help

Comment: This will be down to the browser and/or OS in use. The specs don't put any restrictions on string lengths.

Comment: You can always check the length after the prompt is "confirmed" and repormpt if string is larger. Is not what you want but is a decent workaround.

Comment: you can use create custom prompt like modal and do that stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ECMAScript Programming Language Specification does not specify any maximum
length. The maximum length with will be implementation-specific i.e, based on available memory.

Comment: ECMAScript does not regulate prompt() because it is html specification,

Answer (score 11):

Here are some real world numbers in case anyone is interested.  Please add more if you have any.

Using the following code in the browser console:

`s = prompt("a", Array(SOME_NUMBER).join("0")); s.length;`

- Chrome 43 - **2000** with ellipses as mentioned by @Redzarf.
- Firefox 39 - Reached **10,000,000** then stopped testing (browser runs slowly while this is executing. You may get the 'non responsive script' alert as well).
- IE 11  - Reached **10,000,000** then stopped testing.

Comment: chrome's `2000` limit only applies to prompt's `default` argument. Content you paste into the input itself doesn't have such limit.

Answer (score 5):

As an example, Chrome (v41) limits the 2nd param for prompt() to 2000 characters.

If the value given is longer than that it truncates these 3 strings:

```
first 999 char
'...'
last 998 char
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested on Chrome 72, I was able to input more than 50K char in `prompt`

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse there's no maximum length for prompt() in the spec. In order to limit the length, you'll need to check the length of the result after it's entered.

Answer (score 0):

[karthick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358435/karthick) response was right, but you can check manually for the length of the input prompt this way, forcing the user to only enter less than a set amount of characters, or cancel:

```
var maxLength = 25;
var userData = -1;

while (userData == -1 || (userData != null && userData.length > maxLength)) {
    userData = window.prompt('Please enter some data. It should be no more than ' + maxLength + ' characters in length', ');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
var rep = "+" ;
while (rep != null)
{
    // document.write(rep.length + " " + rep + "<br>") ; // alternate code
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = rep.length + " " + rep + "<br>" ;
    rep = prompt("Input length was : " + rep.length, rep + rep);
}
```

As soon as you respond "Cancel", the navigator displays the last input length and
the corresponding string. Cancel after 262144. Then test further.
For very big length, refreshing the display may take a long time.
I have no actual proof that the displayed string has the correct length.
In the case of 262144 "+", I started tallying visually this string, but I dropped this game after 32 hours (just kidding).