# Javascript console in chrome not returning websites displayed html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I run the following in the JavaScript console in chrome:

```
var doc = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
prompt('test',doc);
```

I receive the following:

```
<head>
<title>****</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* Hide all indicators by default even css bundle is not loaded */
body > div.suspension-indicator-backdrop, body > div[class$='-indicator'] {
display: none;
}
</style>
<link href="/css/bundle/app?v=******" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="/css/bundle/ie?v=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="application/javascript" async="" defer="" src="https://****/track.js?_=****"; }
#intercom-container .intercom-conversation-embed .intercom-sheet-body {
border: none;
z-index: 0; }
#intercom-container .intercom-conversation-embed .intercom-comment-timestamp {
display: none; }
#intercom-container #intercom-embedded-launcher {
z-index: *****;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
height: 48px;
width: 48px;
position: relative; }
#intercom-container #intercom-embedded-launcher.intercom-launcher-with-preview {
width: 340px; }
</style><div id="intercom-launcher" class="intercom-launcher intercom-launcher-active"><div class="intercom-launcher-button"></div>
<div class="intercom-launcher-badge"></div>
<div class="intercom-launcher-preview">
<div class="intercom-launcher-preview-body"></div>
<div class="intercom-launcher-preview-caret"></div>
<div class="intercom-launcher-preview-close"></div>
</div>
</div><div id="intercom-messenger" class="intercom-messenger intercom-messenger-inactive"></div></div></body>
```

The displayed page however has fields, buttons, and other elements that aren't being returned in my prompt. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to get access to those elements through external javascript?

Comment: I believe there is a limit to what you can display in a Javascript prompt box.  It is similar to the alert box. If you need a popup that displays a form or other dynamic/complex information you may want to use third party software such as [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) or write your own.

Comment: Or maybe those elements are dynamically added after your code runs. Or some parts might be CSS pseudo-elements, which are not actually part of the DOM.

Comment: according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969503/prompt-max-length there is no limit

its not adding after my code runs since I am running it from the chrome console.

If it is because they are not actually part of the DOM is there still a way to access that resulting code through javascript?

Comment: If you log it to the console you see the document's complete HTML. IMHO trying to display all that data in a prompt serves no other purpose than for simple debugging ... and I'd argue that isn't very helpful b/c the prompt only shows one line at a time.  `console.log(doc);` for the win!

Comment: prompt was my preference to easily copy data and put it into a text editor to see the result. console.log(doc); leaves me with the same issue that document.documentElement.innerHTML; is not actually getting what is showing in the source of the displayed page.

Comment: That's odd, I was able to reproduce your problem with the prompt, but it seemed to output the document correctly when I logged it to the console. You might try another browser, this weird behavior might only exist in Chrome ;)