# window.prompt() corrupting text

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I want my users to input a JSON. So I execute:

```js
const inputJSON = window.prompt("Enter JSON:");
```

Then I allow the users to edit the JSON like so:

```js
const newJson = window.prompt("Enter new JSON:", inputJSON ); // assume the user doesn't edit the JSON
```

But what I notice is that when I call the prompt function with a default value like above, the text is corrupted:

```js
console.assert(inputJSON  === newJson); // fails!
```

This is the JSON I used:

```
{"$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json","type":"AdaptiveCard","version":"1.0","speak":"<s>Flight KL0605 to San Fransisco has been delayed.</s><s>It will not leave until 10:10 AM.</s>","body":[{"type":"ColumnSet","columns":[{"type":"Column","width":"auto","items":[{"type":"Image","size":"small","url":"https://adaptivecards.io/content/airplane.png"}]},{"type":"Column","width":"stretch","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Flight Status","horizontalAlignment":"right","isSubtle":true},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"DELAYED","horizontalAlignment":"right","spacing":"none","size":"large","color":"attention"}]}]},{"type":"ColumnSet","separator":true,"spacing":"medium","columns":[{"type":"Column","width":"stretch","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Passengers","isSubtle":true,"weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Sarah Hum","spacing":"small"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Jeremy Goldberg","spacing":"small"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Evan Litvak","spacing":"small"}]},{"type":"Column","width":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Seat","horizontalAlignment":"right","isSubtle":true,"weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"14A","horizontalAlignment":"right","spacing":"small"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"14B","horizontalAlignment":"right","spacing":"small"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"14C","horizontalAlignment":"right","spacing":"small"}]}]},{"type":"ColumnSet","spacing":"medium","separator":true,"columns":[{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Flight","isSubtle":true,"weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"KL0605","spacing":"small"}]},{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Departs","isSubtle":true,"horizontalAlignment":"center","weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"10:10 AM","color":"attention","weight":"bolder","horizontalAlignment":"center","spacing":"small"}]},{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Arrives","isSubtle":true,"horizontalAlignment":"right","weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"12:00 AM","color":"attention","horizontalAlignment":"right","weight":"bolder","spacing":"small"}]}]},{"type":"ColumnSet","spacing":"medium","separator":true,"columns":[{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Amsterdam","isSubtle":true},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"AMS","size":"extraLarge","color":"accent","spacing":"none"}]},{"type":"Column","width":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":" "},{"type":"Image","url":"https://adaptivecards.io/content/airplane.png","size":"small"}]},{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"San Francisco","isSubtle":true,"horizontalAlignment":"right"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"SFO","horizontalAlignment":"right","size":"extraLarge","color":"accent","spacing":"none"}]}]}]}
```

---

**TL;DR:** This should be truthy: `longJson == prompt("Just press enter", longJSON)`

**Edit:**

I tested this in my browser:

```js
const json = `{"$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json","type":"AdaptiveCard","version":"1.0","speak":"<s>Flight KL0605 to San Fransisco has been delayed.</s><s>It will not leave until 10:10 AM.</s>","body":[{"type":"ColumnSet","columns":[{"type":"Column","width":"auto","items":[{"type":"Image","size":"small","url":"https://adaptivecards.io/content/airplane.png"}]},{"type":"Column","width":"stretch","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Flight Status","horizontalAlignment":"right","isSubtle":true},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"DELAYED","horizontalAlignment":"right","spacing":"none","size":"large","color":"attention"}]}]},{"type":"ColumnSet","separator":true,"spacing":"medium","columns":[{"type":"Column","width":"stretch","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Passengers","isSubtle":true,"weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Sarah Hum","spacing":"small"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Jeremy Goldberg","spacing":"small"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Evan Litvak","spacing":"small"}]},{"type":"Column","width":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Seat","horizontalAlignment":"right","isSubtle":true,"weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"14A","horizontalAlignment":"right","spacing":"small"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"14B","horizontalAlignment":"right","spacing":"small"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"14C","horizontalAlignment":"right","spacing":"small"}]}]},{"type":"ColumnSet","spacing":"medium","separator":true,"columns":[{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Flight","isSubtle":true,"weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"KL0605","spacing":"small"}]},{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Departs","isSubtle":true,"horizontalAlignment":"center","weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"10:10 AM","color":"attention","weight":"bolder","horizontalAlignment":"center","spacing":"small"}]},{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Arrives","isSubtle":true,"horizontalAlignment":"right","weight":"bolder"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"12:00 AM","color":"attention","horizontalAlignment":"right","weight":"bolder","spacing":"small"}]}]},{"type":"ColumnSet","spacing":"medium","separator":true,"columns":[{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Amsterdam","isSubtle":true},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"AMS","size":"extraLarge","color":"accent","spacing":"none"}]},{"type":"Column","width":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":" "},{"type":"Image","url":"https://adaptivecards.io/content/airplane.png","size":"small"}]},{"type":"Column","width":1,"items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"San Francisco","isSubtle":true,"horizontalAlignment":"right"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"SFO","horizontalAlignment":"right","size":"extraLarge","color":"accent","spacing":"none"}]}]}]}`;
console.log(json == window.prompt("Don't edit. Just press enter.", json);) // false
console.log(json.length); // 2818
console.log(window.prompt("Don't edit. Just press enter.", json).length) // 2000
```

Comment: On SO, your whole question (including any necessary code or data, such as the JSON) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: How is `getOldJson` implemented?

Comment: The `getOldJson()` is missing. Please add it.

Comment: Fixed question.

Comment: Are you sure you have `windows.prompt`? Because it should be `window.prompt` or just drop `window.` part

Comment: I followed your "recipe" in my browser console, and for me, the second variable holds the same string as the first. Have you checked for additional characters, eg line-breaks or carriage-returns?

Comment: I fixed the type with regards to `windows`. I also tested it again in my browser and put the results in my question. @AndreNuechter, I tested the difference using JSON.Parse, where it worked in the initial input and it failed after the prompt, and I also tested the length of the output from `prompt` and put the results in my question

Comment: I did not parse them, but that explains why the check fails: the objects are not the same even though they have the same content.

Comment: That's weird. Characters are chopped off mine so the objects are different. The second errors when I try `JSON.parse`.

Comment: That could be a Chrome-issue, since my first (succeding) test was on firefox and when I tested it on Chrome just now, it failed! And I now know why: the first string is 2818 characters long and the second only 2000.

Comment: Yup. I think your right. Chrome limits it to 2,000 characters. Thank you @AndreNuechter.

Comment: You're welcome. The more you know...

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily compare two Object in JavaScript.

```
{} === {} // return false
```

So you can convert your objects to string and then compare them:

```
console.assert(JSON.stringify(oldJson) === JSON.stringify(newJson));
```

Comment: I was comparing the JSON stings. Not the parsed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the issue. Prompt is only limited to 2000 characters in Chrome. I tested it with this:

```
const expectedLength = 4000;
const actualLength = prompt("Don't edit. Just press enter.", Array(expectedLength).join("0")).length
console.assert(expectedLength == actualLength);
```

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969503/prompt-max-length "Chrome's 2000 limit only applies to prompt's default argument. Content you paste into the input itself doesn't have such limit." Weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in the JSON.
JSON is got overridden and because of that, the values are not matching.
here is the difference of input JSON and output JSON.
[diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/dETQNA5a)